# Is there a programmatical way to find the start and end of a series?

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

I have an equally spaced numbers like this:

```
x 1 2 3 4 y
```

I don't know the start and end values `x` and `y`. `x` can be greater than `y` or vice versa. All I know is the value of the inbetween values and their order in the list, i.e. `1` has an index of `1` (`x`'s index is `0`), `2` has an index of `2`, and so on.

I also know how many numbers in between, so 4 in this case.

Is there a way to formulate this so I can find `x` and `y` using this info?

EDIT: More info:

```
x != y
```

`x > y` or `y > x`

The program generated the numbers inbetween using `x` and `y` given the number of items requested. So a linear interpolation from x to y, using the same increment for each value.

Comment: from what you say so far, it's not at all clear what is the relation between these `x` and `y` and the rest of the series, so I think, you'll need to formulate the problem a bit further. Say, is `0 1 2 3 4 0` a valid sequence? If not, what makes it invalid? And, by the way, `linear algebra` tag does not seem applicable here.

Comment: @Zhenya Surely that's the point of the problem? From looking at the sequence we can deduce that `x` should be zero and `y` should be 5 in this simple example. How can we make a program to do that, especially for harder sequences, I have no idea. However, I think that's what they are asking

Comment: Ok I will add more info, but basically the numbers inbetween are calculated using x and y (not by me), where they start using `x` and end with `y` with equal increments given the number of items needed in between.

Comment: Well, your comment suggests that you've solved your own problem.  If the elements in the series are equally spaced just subtract/add that space from/to the first and last known values.

Comment: Ok that would work but I have multiple of these inbetween numbers of different series mixed in randomly in the final list. So if I have 5 series, than I have 5 items whose index is `1`. Their values are all different given their sequence is different, but I don't have a way to know which `1` and `2` is from the same series.

Comment: @GarethWebber: there are infinitely many sequences which have any number of specific elements coinciding. Thus, for 'deducing' the missing values one needs a rule by which the sequence is constructed. Or, other possible question could be: given a set of numbers from a sequence, construct a possible rule --- and this question does not have a unique answer. Hence asking the OP to clarify what exactly is being asked.

Comment: What does "equal increments" mean? If you mean your sequence is a[0] = x, a[i] = a[i-1] + c. Then the answer is obvious: a[i] = x + i * c. If you have only intermediate values, then the problem is only slightly more complicated.

Comment: It means each element increases linearly, x+a, x+2a, and so on until you reach y.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like linear extrapolation. Try this:

```
def get_xy(values):
    assert(len(values) >= 2)
    #(v1) use the first gain
    m = values[1] - values[0]
    #(v2) calculate the mean-gain
    #     (avg of v[i+1]-v[i])
    m = sum(float(x-y) for x,y in zip(values[1:], values[:-2])) / (len(values) - 1)
    return (values[0] - 1*m, values[-1] + 1*m)

print get_xy([ 1, 2, 3, 4])
print get_xy([-1,-2,-3,-4])
x,y = get_xy([ 1, 2, 3, 4])
print x,y # if you are unfamilar with tuples
```

`v(1)` is fatser but will only work, if every element is incremented/ decremented by the same value (`a(n+1) - a(n) == a(n+2) - a(n+1)` for all `n` if `a`is your sequence). `v(2)` will calculate the mean-gain for all elements. Note that the values are casted to float.